# Perl Script to remove a specific html block from all files in a folder

Tags: python, html, file, perl

I have "help texts" as popup macros on some of our confluence sites and I have to export the sites without these help pop ups as HTML (so attachments are included). My Idea is to run a perl script after the export to remove all help texts which are printed out with the html-tag `<aui-inline-dialog></aui-inline-dialog>`. So I need to remove all theses blocks including the content between them from all html files in a folder.

So far I build up these few code lines :

```
$dirname = '.';
opendir(DIR, $dirname) or die "Could not open $dirname\n";

while ($filename = readdir(DIR)) {
  $perl -ne "print unless /^<aui-inline-dialog>/ .. /^<aui-inline-dialog>$/" "$filename\n";
}

closedir(DIR);
```

Sadly, I'm prompted with the Error "C:\Confluence-space-export-081756-489.html\DATS>perl Perl_Script_for_Removal.pl
syntax error at Perl_Script_for_Removal.pl line 5, near "-ne"
Execution of Perl_Script_for_Removal.pl aborted due to compilation errors."

I never used Perl before and just can't figure out what how to proceed. I read something about an -i switch for perl, in order to edit the files, but I don't know how to use it correctly. I'm on Windows 10 with the Strawberry Perl command line tool. Any suggestions?

Thanks and greetings from Germany

---

So I took the advice and solved this Problem with a Python Script instead of Perl. Here is the python Script and thank you all for the input :

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='./'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.html'):
        fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        with open(fname, 'w') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
            for tag in soup.findAll(True):
                print(tag.name)
                if tag.name=='aui-inline-dialog':
                    i_tag = tag.extract()
            f.write(str(soup))
            f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot switch to shell in the middle of a Perl script. Keep writing Perl:

```perl
my $dirname = '.';
opendir my $dir, $dirname or die "Could not open $dirname: $!\n";
while (my $filename = readdir DIR) {
    open my $file, '<', $filename or die "Could not open $filename: $!\n";
    while (<$file>) {
        print unless /^<aui-inline-dialog>/ .. /^<aui-inline-dialog>$/;
    }
}
```

Also, doesn't the final tag start with `</`?

Moreover, using regexes to parse HTML/XML is a wrong idea. Use a parser instead.

Comment: Yeah, it ends of course with </. When I use your suggestion I get : Regexp modifiers "/a" and "/u" are mutually exclusive at Perl_Script_for_Removal.pl line 6, at end of line
Execution of Perl_Script_for_Removal.pl aborted due to compilation errors. What would you suggest for the parsing, Python? Thank you for your reply and input!

Comment: @DanyelKem That error suggests that you have some syntax error before this code snippet, before the part that you have shown. There are various modules you can install from CPAN to handle HTML properly. [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) would be one option and is easy to use (basically: `my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($file_contents); $_->remove for $dom->find('aui-inline-dialog')->each; print $dom`)

Comment: @DanyelKem That is because you have a slash in your regex now... `/^</aui..../`. You have to escape the slash, or use a different delimiter. `/^<\/aui` or `m#^</aui...#`. Perl interprets "aui" as regex modifiers because the delimiter ends the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a safe way to do it in `perl`, using modules ([`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) and [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)) included in the Strawberry Perl distribution. It's basically the equivalent of the python version using BeautifulSoup.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use Path::Tiny;
use XML::Twig;

my $dir = path(".");
for my $file ($dir->children(qr/\.html$/)) {
    say "Processing $file";
    XML::Twig->new(
        twig_roots => { 'aui-inline-dialog' => sub { $_->delete } },
        twig_print_outside_roots => 1
        )->parsefile_html_inplace($file);
}
```